# Why was my answer deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, specific-answer, deleted-answers

My answer to [Fitting a closed curve on the roots of ${x \choose k}-c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948754/fitting-a-closed-curve-on-the-roots-of-x-choose-k-c) was short but I do not see why it was deleted by a moderator.  In fact, I think it correctly answers the question, though I would of course be interested if someone were to explain to me why it doesn't.

Comment: I do not think it should have been deleted, but I also do not think it answers the question well.  Answering the question "On what curve do the roots of $f(x) = g(x)$ lie?" with "The curve $|f(x)| = |g(x)|$" is kind of a cop out.

Comment: Thanks, @AntonioVargas.  I do now see that it could be considered a cop-out.  On the other hand, maybe it's the best answer there is?  Anyway, I guess this is not a discussion for here...

Comment: I can't disagree that it is, indeed, the most correct answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer went to the review queue, likely because it was so short that the system automatically flagged it. In the review queue, it received many more `delete` votes than `keep` votes, and no upvotes (and, for that matter, 1 downvote). Further, it had another delete vote on it already. Finally, this answer was not helpful to the OP or to the general reader. So I completed the deletion process.

I have now converted it to a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.